Difference between と and に for identity?
宅配業者と見せかけた and 宅配業者に見せかけた
What are the difference between the nuances of these two when they mean almost the same?
And another question why does 見せかける almost function as an intransitive verb despite being transitive? I haven't found any sentences that it uses with を

見せかける can take an object. For example, you can say:

自分を宅配業者(に/と)見せかける
彼の死を自殺(に/と)見せかける
プレゼント(に/と)見せかけた爆弾 (when relativized)

But the object is very commonly "oneself", "it" or "the situation", in which case the object is not usually explicitly specified. Since this verb involves manipulating something, even though it seldom takes an explicit object, it doesn't feel like an intransitive verb to me.
に and と are both very common, and I don't see a significant difference between them. Both can take clauses like so:

事故が起こったように見せかける
事故が起こったと見せかける


I see that makes more sense. It seems like the usages really does depend on the individual verb usage and what it means.
